# Getting information from memory processes

Tags: c++, memory

Everytime i run my software i can access from winhex the memory and read the information my software pass through memory like emails, phones, etc. Is there any way to secure that or at least to remove this information from memory ?

Comment: Yes. Unplug your computer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

A program written to use the debug API, run under the authority of someone who can run a debug API capable app, cannot be protected against.  If it could, you couldn't debug your software.

There is a privilege model:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379306(v=vs.85).aspx

But if someone is running with sufficient privileges to run WinHex and look at that information, then no.  There's no way to exempt your program from inspection from those who have the privileges.

For more interesting security stories...you might be interested in [Cryogenically Frozen Ram Bypasses All Disk Encryption](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/cryogenically-frozen-ram-bypasses-all-disk-encryption-methods/900).